# Unknown run time error when using .End(xlUp) on a range of cells (Code: 800A03EC)

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am attempting to open an excel doc, select an entire column of values up until the last value is found and replace them all with some value. With the following code i am able to select an entire column and replace the values fine, but with no row restriction.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
For Each c in objWorksheet.Range("b1", objWorksheet.Range("b65536"))
    c.Value = "4"
Next

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Although this is a great first step i need to end replacing values on the last found cell in that column. Following the examples in this online resource i used the `.End` property with `xlUp`. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291308/how-to-select-cells-ranges-by-using-visual-basic-procedures-in-excel

I came up with this code that gives an unknown run time error on the `For` line.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
For Each c in objWorksheet.Range("b1", objWorksheet.Range("b65536").End(xlUp))
    c.Value = "4"
Next


objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Is there something i am doing wrong, or is there a better way to achieve the same result that is better?

Comment: You can't use Excel enums in VBScript.  Replace `xlUp` with `-4162`.

Comment: @Comintern Wow thank you very much! this worked! Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Comintern you can just define them `Constant xlUp = -4162`, prefer this to hardcoding numeric values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use excel built-in constant in VBS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941922/how-to-use-excel-built-in-constant-in-vbs)