# recordset.save is saving an empty file vbscript uft

Tags: sql, xml, vbscript, hp-uft

I am trying save a recordset into an xml file. Its creating a xml file at the specified location but its empty. Can someone help me out here?

```
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.open "provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=SEA******;Database=ETL;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
Sql_Statement= ("select top 10 * from employees")
Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(Sql_Statement)
objRecordSet.Save "C:\Documents\Payroll\CompareFiles\db2.xml",adPersistXML
objRecordSet.Close
objConnection.Close
```

Comment: Is `adPersistXML` defined in the code? Should have `Const adPersistXML = 1` somewhere for this to work.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! as soon as i declared the const it worked. :)Thank you once again.

Comment: one more quick question. is there a way to arrange the xml the way we want it? did anyone have sample code on how to use xmlutil in uft?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use excel built-in constant in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941922/how-to-use-excel-built-in-constant-in-vbs) *(Not Excel but missing named constant is the same issue)*.