# External VBS script to open excel file run macro and save as self

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, notepad, save-as

[image]

The code keeps producing this error

seems to be this line
"

```
xlBook.SaveAs Filename:="Template 1", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled
```

"

trying to  run an external VBS script to open excel file run macro and save as self

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample() 

  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook


  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set fname = "mac PIW" 
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\14432\Documents\Custom Office Templates\Template 1.xltm") 
  xlApp.Run "Macro"
  xlBook.SaveAs Filename:="Template 1", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled
  xlBook.Close
  xlApp.Quit 

  Set xlBook = Nothing 
  Set xlApp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as the named parameters problem noted by Geert Bellekens, you have a number of other problems:

- VBScript won't know what `xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled` is ... replace it with its numeric value of 53
- You are using a blanket `On Error Resume Next` which is hiding problems in your script
- You use `Option Explicit` and also have an undeclared variable `fname`
- You say "and save as self" but when you call `Workbooks.Open` you are creating a new Workbook from the Template instead of opening the Template itself

Proposed code (assuming that you do want to actually re-save the Template itself, not a Workbook created from the Template):

```
Option Explicit

ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample() 

  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  ' force the Template to open as itself instead of creating a new Workbook
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\14432\Documents\Custom Office Templates\Template 1.xltm", , , , , , , , , True) 
  ' in case there is a problem while running the macro or saving the file, we still want to ensure we quit Excel
  On Error Resume Next 
  xlApp.Run "Macro"
  xlBook.Save
  xlBook.Close False
  xlApp.Quit 

  Set xlBook = Nothing 
  Set xlApp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please do not suggest placing magic numbers in place of constants, just define them yourself, i.e. `Const xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled = 53`. See [How to use excel built-in constant in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39941922). Not sure why you thought you needed to answer this question when it was already flagged with multiple duplicate targets.

Comment: 1.I was providing the questioner with a working script ... not a perfect script. 2. I answered the question before it was closed. It isn't possible to answer closed questions.

Comment: I said it was flagged not closed, it's clear to see that there are duplicate targets before a question is closed.

Comment: There were no duplicate targets when I opened the web page to answer the question. As my crystal ball is currently not working then I could not have known it was going to be flagged, closed or whatever at some future point.