# Does VBScript allow named arguments in function calls?

Tags: vbscript, named-parameters

I am trying to run the following code in `VBScript` but it is not compiling the last statement.  Is it because `VBScript` doesn't allow named arguments?

```
Filename_Argument = WScript.Arguments(0)
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Filename_Argument, Origin _
        :=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
        , Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|", FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Answer (score 12):

VBScript doesn't support named arguments to procedures and functions. You need to change the argument list to positional:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename_Argument, xlMSDOS, ...
```

VBScript also doesn't recognize Excel constants (like `xlMSDOS`), so you need to look them up and replace them with their numeric values:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename_Argument, 3, ...
```

And you must use explicit object references:

```
objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText Filename_Argument, 3, ...
```

The Excel Macro Recorder puts named arguments into positional order, so you can just delete the parameter names. Optional parameters that you don't want to specify can be omitted, e.g.:

```
x = Function(Var1, , Var3)
'                 ^
'                 `- omitted optional 2nd parameter
```

Comment: To the downvoter, if you think this is a bad answer then why not add an answer yourself?

Comment: ... or at least explain what you consider wrong about an essentially correct answer.

Comment: I prefer to keep the Named Constants and declare them using `Const`, so would be `Const xlMSDOS = 3`, rather than using literal numeric values.

Comment: Relevant to [using named constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39956808/692942).