# Unprotect multiple word documents inside a folder using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, wsh

I have multiple word documents, which need restrictions imposed on them from Developer mode.

I run the script using wscript passing a folder as argument, But it throes an error

```
Dim strFolder
Const xlTypePDF = 0
strFolder = WScript.Arguments(0)

if  Wscript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

    For Each Fil In objFolder.Files
        Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(Fil)

        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Fil,,TRUE)
        dirPath = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile)
        fileBaseName = objFSO.GetBaseName(objFile)

'objWord.ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:="pwd" 

        objWord.ActiveDocument.Close(False)
    Next

    objWord.Quit
Else
    Msgbox("Run usning cmd")
End If
```

Comment: What error does it throw, and on which line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194300/does-vbscript-allow-named-arguments-in-function-calls

Comment: What is the text of the error?

Comment: `Fil` will just give you the name of the file, not the full path.. Try `Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(objFSO..BuildPath(strFolder, Fil),,TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub UnprotectDocsInFolder()
Dim docfile As Document
Dim docpath As String
Dim docfilename As String
Dim pwd As String

    'Path for the documents
    docpath = "C:\ProtectedDocs\"
    'Password
    pwd = "myPass"

    docfilename = Dir(docpath & "*.doc")

    Do Until docfilename = ""
        Set docfile = Documents.Open(docpath & docfilename)
        docfile.Unprotect pwd
        docfile.Close True
        docfilename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

You can use similar code to protect files in same manner.

```
Sub ProtectDocsInFolder()
Dim docfile As Document
Dim docpath As String
Dim docfilename As String
Dim pwd As String

    'Path for the documents
    docpath = "C:\UnProtectedDocs\"
    'Password
    pwd = "myPass"

    docfilename = Dir(docpath & "*.doc")

    Do Until docfilename = ""
        Set docfile = Documents.Open(docpath & docfilename)
        docfile.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, , pwd
        docfile.Close True
        docfilename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```