# Integrating VBA inside VBScript file

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have a working VBScript file and VBA macro inside Excel worksheet that does this:

- Refreshes all data connections
- Writes a timestamp in a specific cell
- Save and closs the Excel worksheet

VBS file:

```
 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

 objExcel.Application.Run "'G:\Blank.xlsm'!Module9.Date"
 objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
 objExcel.Application.Quit

 Set objExcel = Nothing
```

VBA inside the Blank.xlsm worksheet:

```
Sub Date()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    With Range("M12")
        .Value = Now()
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm"
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End With
End Sub
```

Is it possible to keep the Excel macro-free .xslx file and run both of those functions from a VBScript file, which would not call the macro inside the Excel workbook to do the things I need, but rather complete those tasks by itself? I'm very new to VBScript (and frankly, VBA, too), so I'm sorry if this comes as too basic of a question.

Comment: Look into using an XLAM file (Excel Add-in) which can operate on a code free XLSX file.

Comment: Are you sure your VBA code compiles as is? You can't have a method named `Date`!

Comment: Please don't edit the question to add additional requirements after receiving an answer _and accepting it_. If you have another question, you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course, it's possible. Here:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objExcel, objWorkBook

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)

objExcel.Application.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

objWorkBook.RefreshAll

With objWorkBook.Sheets(1).Range("M12")
    .Value = Now()
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm"
End With

objWorkBook.Save
objWorkBook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Works like a charm, big thanks! I added a write protection for the workbook though and struggling to properly add password operator to the Worksbooks.Open method - will update the OP.

Comment: @dotsent12 Please don't edit the question to add additional requirements. If you have another question, you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Anyway, for this specific issue, you don't have to ask a new question because it's been asked before several times. Since [VBScript doesn't support named arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42194325/4934172), you should use `objExcel.Workbooks.Open (filePath,,,,, "WritePassword")`.