# How to convert Pivot tabel from VBA macro in Vbscript?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I'm new to Macros. I want to do pivot table of a data. I can't use VBA macros inside excel, instead I can use externally as writing in VBscript & execute as ".VBS" file. Though I managed to create excel objects & putting data but I'm facing difficulty in creating pivot table. I am aware that VBA & vbscript are similar, so I tried using VBA as shown in the following:

> First I tried creating excel objects using Vbscript:

```
Set obj = createobject("Excel.Application")
obj.visible = True
Set obj1 = obj.Workbooks.Add
obj.Cells(1,1).Value = "NM"
obj.Cells(1,2).Value = "VL"
obj.Cells(2,1).Value = "A"
obj.Cells(2,2).Value = 1
obj.Cells(3,1).Value = "B"
obj.Cells(3,2).Value = 2
obj.Cells(4,1).Value = "C"
obj.Cells(4,2).Value = 3
obj.Cells(5,1).Value = "D"
obj.Cells(5,2).Value = 4
```

[image: Excel using Vbscript]

> Then I tried using VBA macros (bulit-in excel macro) for pivoting table in excel file itself.

```
    Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C1:R5C2", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Sheet2!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("VL")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("NM")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("NM").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("NM")
        .PivotItems("A").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("C").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("NM"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    Application.Goto Reference:="Macro1"
End Sub
```

[image: Pivot Table using excel VBA]

> Now I am trying to do the same using VBScript but I am not getting it.
>   I tried using the same & did changes like adding excel object name
>   before methods but still not working.

```
Set obj = createobject("Excel.Application")
obj.visible = True
Set obj1 = obj.Workbooks.Add
obj.Cells(1,1).Value = "NM"
obj.Cells(1,2).Value = "VL"
obj.Cells(2,1).Value = "A"
obj.Cells(2,2).Value = 1
obj.Cells(3,1).Value = "B"
obj.Cells(3,2).Value = 2
obj.Cells(4,1).Value = "C"
obj.Cells(4,2).Value = 3
obj.Cells(5,1).Value = "D"
obj.Cells(5,2).Value = 4

'Tried making changes:

'Adding Excel object
Obj.ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C1:R5C2", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Sheet2!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6

'Even Adding Excel workbook object
Obj1.ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            "Sheet1!R1C1:R5C2", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
            "Sheet2!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
```

It is showing error of bracket missing so I even tried to put it as single line.

```
 obj.ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="R1C1:R6C2", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _"Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
```

But still showing same error as "**Error : Expected ')'** " (*in the above same line*). However, it is proper syntax in for VBA macros, but during vbscript executing, it is throwing error. is there any syntax difference or changes that need to be done.

Can anyone please help me or suggest me how to do it or get it done.

Comment: "not working" is not a useful description of the problems you're seeing with your code.  Please show your current code and explain what error(s) you see, and on which line(s).  Also review (for example) this guide: https://help.mjtnet.com/article/19-converting-office-vba-to-vbscript

Comment: @TimWilliams - Hi Tim, I've updated the question & thanks for the link. I'll checkout.

Comment: That should give you the information you're looking for.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Hey Tim, I saw that & it stating same that we need to add excel objects if called outside as many functions are defined in excel can called directly but to execute it in outside, need to add objects & define. I guess need to do trial & error now. Well, thanks again for the link.

Comment: [Related](https://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Thanks Ansgar I'll try it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does VBScript allow named arguments in function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194300/does-vbscript-allow-named-arguments-in-function-calls)

Comment: @GeertBellekens - Hi Geert, the question is different. It is asking whether it is allowed or not, whereas I'm already aware it does not, so I'm asking what's the better way & not just that, the question is about creating pivot table also.

Comment: The question might be different, the answer is the same. VBScript doesn't support named arguments, and that is the reason for the errors you are getting. If you solve that you'll probably have no problems replicating the VBA code in VBScript.

Comment: @GeertBellekens - Thanks Geert, I will definitely look forward to that problem by replacing the excel vba objects.