# Using Find Method in Vbscript for search Word file. Can find character but not replace

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, find

I am trying to search through Word documents and try to find a certain character. The ± character to be precise. The code can find the character because I have it print to screen if it found it. But it is unable to replace the character.

I have even tried searching for a random string I knew was in the files such as "3" and replacing it with something random such as "dog". But nothing works. It still finds the characters but does not replace.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWord, objDoc, objSelection, oFSO, folder, jj, file

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False: objWord.DisplayAlerts = False
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\myFolder")

For Each file In folder.Files
        objWord.Documents.Open file.path, False, True ' path, confirmconversions, readonly

        Set objDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument
        Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

        objSelection.Find.Forward = True
        objSelection.Find.MatchWholeWord = False
        objSelection.Find.Text = ChrW(177)
        objSelection.Find.Replacement.Text = "ChrW(177)"

        objSelection.Find.Execute

        If objSelection.Find.Found = True then
                Wscript.echo "Character Found"
        End If
        objDoc.close
Next
objWord.Quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the code in the question doesn't specify that a replacement should take place. This is set in the `Execute` method, as a parameter.

Since this is VBScript rather than VBA it's not possible to use the enumerations (such as `wdReplaceAll`). Instead, it's necessary to specify the numeric equivalent of an enumeration. VBA without enumerations...

```
objSelection.Find.Execute Replace:=2, Forward:=True, Wrap:=0
```

**However**, VBScript [doesn't accept named arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42194325/3077495), so all the arguments need to be specified *by position*, with "empty commas" if nothing should be specified.

```
 objSelection.Find.Execute , , , , , , , 0, , , 2
```

To discover the numeric equivalent consult either the VBA Object Library (F2 in the VBA Editor), the Language Reference or use the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) in the VBA Editor like this: `?wdReplaceAll` then press Enter.

Comment: I still get a compile error on that line saying "Expected Statement". I have tried everything to get it to run. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
 objSelection.Find.Execute
```

should be

```
 objSelection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
```

(assuming you want to replace all occurrences

This code running inside a word module will replace all "cat" with "dog"

```
Sub test()
Dim objdoc As Document
Dim objSelection As Range
Set objdoc = ActiveDocument
        Set objSelection = Selection.Range

        With objSelection.Find
            .Forward = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .Text = "Cat"
            .Replacement.Text = "Dog"

            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue

            If .Found Then
                  Debug.Print "Found"
            End If
        End With
End Sub
```

However you're running in vbscript using late binding, so possibly there's a type issue - you're selection object may not be a range but a variant?

Comment: That still throws a compile error at that line saying "Expected Statement"