# Saving an active worksheet in excel workbook as PDF file with VB Script

Tags: pdf, vbscript

Request your help.

I am trying to save the values in a range of cells in an active worksheet of the excel workbook that is open, as a PDF file.

I am using the following code for the same.

```
Dim objExcel
Dim objExcelPayrollDetailsWB
Dim objExcelEmpDetailWS
Dim objExcelPayslipWS

Dim strExcelFilePath
StrExcelFilePath = "D:\Salary\PayrollProcessing\Sample Salary Statement Sep-2019.xlsx"

Dim strPdfPaysliPath
strPdfPaysliPath = "D:\Salary\PayrollProcessing\GeneratedPayslips\"

Dim strPayslipFileNameWithPath
Dim strPaySlipName
Dim strPaySlipMonthYear

' Initiate Excel Application
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

' Specify the Excel workbook to be opened and the logical local drive path where the workbook is available
Set objExcelPayrollDetailsWB = objExcel.Workbooks.open(strExcelFilePath)

' Set the focus to the required worksheet
Set objExcelEmpDetailWS = objExcelPayrollDetailsWB.Worksheets("BLRCC")

strPaySlipMonthYear = objExcelEmpDetailWS.Cells(5,4).Value
strPaySlipMonthYear = Month(strPaySlipMonthYear)&"-"&Year(strPaySlipMonthYear)

Set objExcelPayslipWS = objExcelPayrollDetailsWB.Worksheets("BLRCC PS")

strPaySlipName = objExcelPayslipWS.Cells(15,15).Value&"_"&strPaySlipMonthYear

strPayslipFileNameWithPath = strPdfPaysliPath & strPaySlipName & ".pdf"

' Code to save the active worksheet (the payslip worksheet in the 'PayrollDetailsWB') as PDF in a specific path
'   *SAVE Payslip as a PDF document*
'   *************************************
'   Save a range as PDF
    objExcelPayslipWS.Range("A1:AB55").Select
    MsgBox "The name of the active sheet is: " & (objExcelPayrollDetailsWB.ActiveSheet.Name)

    objExcel.Activeworkbook.Save

    objExcel.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat 0, Filename:= _
        strPayslipFileNameWithPath, Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

When I execute it, a Microsoft VBScript compilation error, stating,

> "Expected statement" is thrown at the line,
>   objExcel.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat 0, Filename:= _

Comment: VBScript doesn't have named parameters, you can't do `Filename:=`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does VBScript allow named arguments in function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194300/does-vbscript-allow-named-arguments-in-function-calls)

Comment: Thank you Ben. The following script finally worked. 'objExcelPayslipWS.Range("A1:AB55").ExportAsFixedFormat 0, strPayslipFileNameWithPath,0, 1, 0,,,0'