# VBS, Save Copy of file name as with todays date

Tags: vba

I am running a VBS and trying to save a copy of the file with the newest date.

currently I use  `wb.Save` which saves the current copy nicely.

Anyone know why these two attempts dont work? The dialog box closes immediately when trying these two different attempts.

```
   wb.SaveCopyAs Filename:="O:\Desktop\Export " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm"
    wb.Save Filename:="O:\Desktop\Export " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm"
```

Thanks.

Comment: What dialog box?

Comment: sorry the black cmd prompt box.

Comment: A bit more detail might be useful here around exactly how you launch your vbscript.  Maybe that folder doesn't exist on your Desktop (are you missing a "\" after Export) ?

Comment: Maybe this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194300/does-vbscript-allow-named-arguments-in-function-calls   Note sure you can use named arguments in VBScript.